# bootstrap datepicker shows up in a top left corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have this problem with my bootstrap datepicker. I click the button which pops the datepicker but it shows in upleft corner, also it cannot be closed and it won't call function onchangeDate. This is really drivig me mad. Here's a HTML part of code.

```html
<a href="#" class="btn small" id="selecteddate" onclick="showDatePicker()" >yyyy-MM-DD</a>
```

and here is a javascript function which craetes the datepicker

```javascript
function onload(){
$('#selecteddate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    pickTime: false,
    maskInput: false,
    autoclose: true
});

$('#selecteddate').on('changeDate', function(ev) {
    alert("asd");
    date = $("#selecteddate").data("datetimepicker").getDate();
});
. . .
```

}

thanks in advance for every reply :)

EDIT: oops, I have forgotten the showdatepicker()

```js
function showDatePicker(){
    $('#selecteddate').datetimepicker("show");
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link you your page so I can see if there are any javascript errors?

Comment: can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces your issue?

Comment: firstly, thanks for the answers. secondly, unfortunately I dont have a link to my page and I cant provide you the whole js code :(. Im trying to copy it to jsfiddle, but I havent worked with it yet and I cannot make it work >:(